# preg_replace(), no ending delimiter '$' found

Tags: php, windows, apache, preg-replace

Alright, this problem seems to be way above my head!

I have this code:

```
$request=preg_replace('$(^'.str_replace('$','\$',$webRoot).')$i','',$requestUri);
```

This throws me an error:

**preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '$' found**

But here's the thing, that ending delimeter is certainly there.

After that function call I echoed out the following:

```
echo $webRoot;
echo $requestUri;
echo '$(^'.str_replace('$','\$',$webRoot).')$i';
```

This is the result of those echoes:

```
/
/en/example/
$(^/)$i
```

What is funny is that if I do this directly:

```
preg_replace('$(^/)$i','',$requestUri);
```

..it works. But this also fails:

```
$tmp=str_replace('$','\$',$webRoot);
preg_replace('$(^'.$tmp.')$i','',$requestUri);
```

And just to be thorough, I also tested what echo $tmp gives, and it does give the proper value:

```
/
```

Is it a bug in PHP in Windows? I tried it out on Linux server and it worked as expected, it didn't throw this error. Or am I missing something?

Just to make sure, I even updated PHP to latest Windows version (5.4.2) and the same thing happens.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a meta-character as a delimiter?

Comment: Do you get the same error when using a different delimiter, such as `/` or `#`?

Comment: I originally used / as a delimiter (this is why I had the str_replace there, since I was dealing with URL's). Dollar sign was what I used after trying to trial&error for the solution.

Comment: @kristovaher:  Use a different delimiter than `$` (`/` is very common), and in place of `str_replace`, use `preg_quote($webRoot, '/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I personally would use another character as a delimiter like '#' since the $ char is a regexp special char which matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to. That said the few times I had to work on windows servers I found that every regular expressions has to be passed through preg_quote function, nevermind if it contains or not regexp special chars.

```
$request=preg_replace('#(^'.preg_quote($webRoot).')#i','',$requestUri);
```

Comment: For some reason.. Bingo. Apparently Windows does not like the manual delimeter string replace for some reason. But preg_quote works. This is a problem that wasn't the case with older PHP versions, as I've had code run in that environment before, but apparently it's an issue now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

abidibo's answer is correct, but apparently the problem was caused by a bug in str_replace() function. For some reason, in Windows Apache and nginx, this function corrupts the string and pads it with symbols that cannot be read.

Comment: Probably you are right but I'm quite sure that php + Windows requires preg_quote even if  the regexp string is not passed through str_replace, at least this happened to me developing a php framework on a WAMP environment, can't remember which 5

Comment: Pardon (writing from mobile), concluding I can't remember which 5.x php version I was running. Cheers!

Comment: Actually no, it does not, I ran the same test on The Uniform Server with the latest PHP and Apache and this did not happen. This str_replace() but seemingly only happened with nginx and PHP. There's something very wrong there. But your tip was good, since that is the proper way of escaping for a regular expression.